# STATA margins dydx with over(.), continuous variables and interaction effect

Tags: logistic, data-visualization, stata, marginal-effect

I have a logistic regression model with two variables (A and B), which I also interact. A and B are both continuous. After the estimation I want to use the margins command to plot the marginal effect of A over the range of B values. As far as I understood this should go by using:

```
margins, dydx(A) over(B)
```

However, STATA throws the following error:

```
only integer values are allowed in by() variables
r(198)
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Over calculates the marginal effects within each over group, so only makes sense for categorical variables. You maybe want something like `margins, dydx(A) at(B=(0(0.1)5))`, where I pretended the range of B is from 0 to 5 (and generate the effects at every 0.1 interval in between). So this is the marginal effect of A conditional on a particular value of B, averaging over the entire sample in the current dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think that solved it! Your explanation makes sense to me. :)